# How do I compare hardware on two machines?

Tags: windows-xp, benchmarking, windows-experience-index

I am trying to compare the hardware performance on two machines. One of those machines is Windows 7 and for that I can get the Windows Experience Index. The other machine is XP. Is there a way to generate the Windows Experience Index on an XP machine?

If not, what software would you recommend I run to objectively compare the hardware components on these two machine to generate a single figure?

Comment: Search on Google for benchmarking programs.

Comment: Windows Experience is hardly a fair comparison. For example, most $150+ graphics cards will max out the graphics comparison. Benchmarking tools will give you a much more in-depth look of which one is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Windows Experience Index in Windows XP.

Run **[GeekBench](http://www.primatelabs.ca/geekbench/)** on each machine and you'll get a "single figure" result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Futuremark's tools](http://www.futuremark.com/). They have various benchmarking programs for different aspects of your machine, most have a basic version which is free or trialware.